# setValue on FormControl is not reflected in View

Tags: angular, form-control

I want to load an existing value into a FormControl to be able to update the value in my database.

My code (shortened and boiled down to an example) looks as follows. Clicking the edit button shall load the referring name from the array into the FormControl.

**App-Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {

  nameForm = new FormControl(['']);
  names = ['Peter', 'Bob', 'Mary']

  updateName (id : number): void {
      this.nameForm.setValue(this.names[id]);
  }   
}
```

**HTML-Template**

```
 <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let name of names; index as i">
                <td>{{i + 1}}  : </td><td>{{name}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button (click)="updateName(i)">Edit</button>
                  </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
<input type="text" formControlName="nameForm">
```

I have constructed an example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7vm4y.
Clicking on edit does not set the value into the FormControl. Where is my mistake?

Thanks and best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding a FormGroup as shown below:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name">
</form>
```

TS:

```
name = new FormControl(['']);
names = ['Peter', 'Bob', 'Mary']
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
 this.form=this.fb.group({
   name:['']
 })
}

updateName (id : number): void {
  this.form.get('name').setValue(this.names[id]);
}
```

For more info refer:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the form in a form group and set the value using it. Try the following

Controller

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    nameForm: new FormControl('')
  });
  names = ['Peter', 'Bob', 'Mary']

  updateName (id : number): void {
    this.form.get('nameForm').setValue(this.names[id]);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let name of names; index as i">
    <td>{{i + 1}}  : </td><td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="updateName(i)">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="nameForm">
</form>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-humba7)

Comment: Yupp, that was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix, change this line:

`<input type="text" formControlName="nameForm">`

to this:

`<input type="text" [formControl]="nameForm">`

---

`formControlName` is used as part of a `FormGroup`, to effectively refer to a child within that group with the string name of the child, almost in the way that you would pass a key to an object using `object[ 'key' ]`

If you are not using a `FormGroup` as a parent for your `FormControl`s, then you simply need to bind that `FormControl` into the HTML element directly, hence the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<input type="text" [formControl]="nameForm">
```

because you need formGroup for formControlName.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to set the value of a form control to null in Angular, but the value is not being reflected in the view.

I'm using the following code:

```
this.formControlName.setValue("");
```

Comment: This seems like a question/problem you have, not an answer to the given question.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. I faced this issue before. Instead of setting it to 'null,' I used an empty string '', and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Angular to detect changes.

```
import { Component , ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {

  nameForm = new FormControl(['']);
  names = ['Peter', 'Bob', 'Mary'];

  constructor(private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  updateName (id : number): void {
      this.nameForm.setValue(this.names[id]);

      //trigger change
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }   
}
```